# Help finding 70s-80s sci-fi smut-ish book

Tags: identification-request

Recently I remembered a book that I had a hilarious encounter with when I was younger. Read the blurb on the back, grabbed it, and brought it to school in middle school.

It was effectively a Sci-Fi smut story (And the school was a religious school). And from what I remember it wasn't even written that well.

Now, I can't remember much about the book but due to the hilarity of the circumstances I originally saw it, I'm curious if anyone can help me identify it.

Here's what I know/think I know
It was from the 70s or 80s, with a yellow cover with a round bit of artwork on it.
The story started out with the Protagonist Male and Female companion in an escape craft/lifeboat
They had decided to go naked to "spare their outfits from wear and tear" or some other absurdly forced concept.

*Some time later* they are retrieved/rescued/wind up in the care of some alien. This alien sets up some sort of place to watch over them and apparently has the goal of getting them to have sex. They refuse? And the alien tries to get them with an aphrodisiac of some sort. Eventually at some point they're attacked by a bicycle whose handlebars spin around and knives come out the end.

I didn't actually read the whole thing, just bits and pieces here and there - Even my young-teen self thought the writing wasn't that grand. I want to find it to see just how accurate my memories of it are.

Comment: Maybe you'd be more likely to get an answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/  ?

Comment: That... makes a lot of sense, actually. Somehow I saw "Literature" and didn't even *think* about Sci-Fi

Comment: Hardcover or paperback? American or British? Did it have illustrations? Was the lifeboat floating on the water or in outer space?

Comment: Don't worry - your question is perfectly acceptable here also ;). There's no real reason to push questions away to another site when they're perfectly on topic here, @WGroleau - you may want to check out [this meta question](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/278/58).

Comment: @Mithrandir perfectly reasonable to suggest that they might have more success elsewhere though? It might turn out to be a well known bit of kitsch that everyone as SciFi has the name of at their fingertips..

Comment: @Spagirl Don't worry, all of Scifi.SE's top experts on answering story-ID questions are also active here (one of them has already commented on this question, even). This site needs more activity, and SFF doesn't :-)

Comment: Blades on the handlebars makes me think of Daniel Suarez's *Demon* books, but those are much more recent.

Comment: @user14111 Space setting. Paperback. No illustrations that I remember.

Comment: As a newbie to this site, I will hopefully remember that.  :-)  I was directed from there to this site when I wanted to identify a NON-scifi book.

Comment: @WGroleau To be completely fair, though, you're not completely wrong. Just because it's a perfectly fine question here doesn't mean it wouldn't *also* be a perfectly fine question there as well.

Comment: My first thought on reading this is maybe one of the "A. Bertram Chandler" John Grimes series books. They were a bit smutty, but only PG-13 or a little R, they were not Hard R or XXX smutty. I do recall that exercise bikes were mentioned it a few books, and the event described seems typical of the situations John Grimes found himself in.